# How can I add keyfram3 to move from right to left

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have card items in html.

As you see there are 8 card items. What I am trying to achieve is I want to add a keyframe to move that from right to left and when I hover over one of the card items, I want it to stop. Since I want it continuously like a chain turn over and over, I couldn't figure out how to do it. Can I achieve this only with css?

```css
.card {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  filter: brightness(0.9) saturate(0);
}

.card:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 150%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 24px;
  bottom: 0;
  filter: brightness(0.75) saturate(1.2) contrast(0.85);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: center;
  trsnsform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
  transition: filter 200ms linear, transform 200ms linear;
}

.card:hover {
  filter: unset;
}

.card:hover .card-background {
  transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557177324-56c542165309?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557177324-56c542165309?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557177324-56c542165309?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557187666-4fd70cf76254?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556680262-9990363a3e6d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557004396-66e4174d7bf6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556680262-9990363a3e6d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-background" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557004396-66e4174d7bf6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I didnt add my keyframe because I dont know how can I make it. Literally, I am trying to achieve full turn, like when it goes out from the window something else should come infinitely.

Comment: Where is the CSS? I made a snippet

Comment: Just added the css

Comment: Next time update the snippet!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your css file.

```
.card {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  filter: brightness(0.9) saturate(0);
  width: 10%;
  animation: lefttoright 5s linear 2s infinite alternate; //name duration timing-function delay count direction 
}
@keyframes lefttoright {
  0%{
    left: 0;
  }
  50%{
    left: 50%;
  }
  100%{
    left: 0;
  }
}

.card:hover {
  filter: unset;
  animation-play-state: paused; //stop animation when hover on each item
}
```

It's done.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for something like when it reaches the end, it starts from the beginning and as you see there is 8 items but 6 of them should be shown and it should slide to right in loop

Comment: @magicbean just delete 50%{...} in keyframes and change 100%{left:0} to 100%{left:100%}